# Swift deprecated .. operator for creating arrays

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I used swift in an early project using the non definitive version of it, and the code above worked fine:

```
for i in 0..array.count{
   //anything
}
```

when i downloaded the definitive version, the error:

> use of uresolved identifier '..'

shows up. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax has changed to this for 0 up to less than array.count

```
for i in 0..<array.count{
    //anything
}
```

or to 0 up to an including array.count

```
for i in 0...array.count{
    //anything
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** As posted in offcial swift blog from `Xcode 6 beta version 3` the syntax for the half open range has changed.

**As it says in official swift blog:**

`The half-open range operator has been changed from .. to ..< to make it more clear alongside the ... operator for closed ranges.`

**As per new syntax:**

```
for i in 0..<array.count{

  // Do something

}
```